# ¿como graficas mapas a partir de dos o mas shapefile?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mapa, folium

estoy iniciándome en geopandas. Cargue 2 archivos shp (shapefile) y necesito generar la grafica (mapas). Básicamente que las patentes de alcoholes se muestre en las unidades vecinales.

unidades_vecinales = gdp.read_file(r"C:\Usersxxxx.shp")

pantentes_alcoholes = gdp.read_file(r"C:\Usersxxxx.shp")

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: estoy tratando de poder proyectar los shapefile. este es el codigo para proyectar con matplotlib                       ´unidades_sanfelipe = gdp.overlay(san_felipe, unidades_vecinales, how = "intersection" )
unidades_sanfelipe.plot(figsize = (20, 12))´                                                                    me proyecta un imagen en blanco con este mensaje: UserWarning: CRS mismatch between the CRS of left geometries and the CRS of right geometries.
Use `to_crs()` to reproject one of the input geometries to match the CRS of the other.
Left CRS: EPSG:3857
Right CRS: EPSG:32719